# Tflearn issue over model.load

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

```
# restore all of our data structures
import pickle
import tflearn
import tensorflow as tf
import random
...
# load our saved model
model.load('./model.tflearn')

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    # stem each word
```

my error

```
$ python wrapper.py

Scipy not supported!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 18, in <module>
    model.load('./model.tflearn')
NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

any help ?

[image: This is my directory]

and my model write code looks like

```
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

I am developing a chatbot using tflearn, I trained the model and saved the model but when I load it again then it throws a error , both the python files in same directory and models are in same dir too..

Comment: You did not declare the variable `model`. You need to define what `model` is first, before you can load anything. E.g. `model = DNN(network)`. See (http://tflearn.org/getting_started/) under 'Training, Evaluating & Predicting' for an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# load our saved model
model.load('./model.tflearn')
```

I forgot to mention the variable model and this made the error to pop out.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: `NotFoundError: Key Accuracy/Mean/moving_avg_1 not found in checkpoint
  [[node save_5/RestoreV2 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py:153) ]]`